# A-Frame animations via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, aframe

I started with A-Frame VR framework. I have a simple box that I want to animate.

This box will be floating, when looking to the box, it will scale up, on click it will rotate:

```
<a-box id="boxID" position="0 2 -5" rotation="0 45 45" scale="2 2 2" src="#boxTexture">
            <a-animation attribute="position" to="0 2.2 -5" direction="alternate" dur="2000" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>

<!-- These animations will start when the box is looked at. -->
<a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseenter" dur="300" to="2.3 2.3 2.3"></a-animation>
<a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseleave" dur="300" to="2 2 2"></a-animation>
<a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="click" dur="2000" to="360 405 45"></a-animation>
```

I would like to create above with Javascript. I started with the following:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('scale-on-interact', {
    schema: {
        to: {default: '2.5 2.5 2.5'}
    }, 

    init: function () {
        var data = this.data;

    }, 

    update: function() {
        var data = this.data;
        console.log(data.color);

        // MOUSE ENTER EVENT
        this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
            console.log("enter");
            this.setAttribute('to', data.to);
        });

        // CLICK EVENT
        this.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log("click");
        });

        // MOUSE LEAVE EVENT
        this.el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
            console.log("leave");
        });
    }
});
```

I receive the logs, but for example on mouse enter, the box doesn't scale up. Also I doesn't know and can't find how to create multiple schema's so I can create one 'to' property for on mouse enter and one for on click.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the `<a-animation>` and [Animation Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-component) both take `begin` and `startEvents` properties that specify an event on the entity that will automatically trigger the animation. `<a-animation begin="mouseenter">` or `<a-entity animation__1="property: scale; to: 2 2 2; startEvents: click">`.

Secondly, there's an [`event-set` component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/event-set) that might do what you want, set properties in response to events. `<a-entity event-set__1="_event: mouseenter; scale: 2 2 2">`.

Third, in your component, if you want to set the scale, you should `setAttribute('scale', {x: 2, y: 2, z: 2})`, not `to`. Also makes sure that component is attached to your entity `<a-box id="boxID" scale-on-interact>`.

Lastly, if you want a component to be able to have multiple instances, set `multiple: true` in your component. Then you can have multiple components set with `__` delimiter: `<a-box id="boxID" component__1="foo: 1; bar: 2" component__two="foo: 2; bar: 3">`